# Identify Windows run time exception in console application

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, continuous-integration, runtime-error, console-application

I have 1000+ C# windows app samples for my product. Before shipping to my customers I would like to see is there any run time exception occur in each windows samples? In our continues integration process we had ensured the compilation of each windows app samples.

We have written the console application to execute the each window application trying to identify the run time exception in console application. Do you have any idea about this please?

Comment: Make unit tests for them?

Comment: No. I no need unit test for them

Comment: Unit tests would test your applications.. thats the whole point of them.. if you dont wish to do that.. then you can employ some poor soul who has to do exactly the same manually - there isnt a lot of choice